# Docker-compose django nginx doesnt find static files

Tags: django, docker, nginx, gunicorn

I'm trying to dockerize my application and i'm almost done. The only issue I have is that nginx doesn't find my static files. I've searched all over the web, but I havent found a solution yet.

I made a volume that's shared between the Django application and the Nginx server, and in my `settings.py` I pointed the settings to that, but no luck.

I'm not sure how many of the files you need to inspect, so I uploaded the whole project to Github.

https://github.com/temp3020102/django_project

When the image has been built and you navigate to `http://localhost/admin` one can see that the CSS is missing.

I'm aware that posting the `secret_key` and such to the internet is not a good idea, and i'm of course changing that once I have a fix for the issue. It's just there for the sake of your convenience.

Comment: Questions with no code are not respected here. Please share your settings.py part for static and media files, dockerfile and, I guess, docker-compose file. Also it's not clear now which specific one of the services reports which concrete HTTP status - please check your log files and share this info as well.

Answer (score 0):

You are referring to /home/app/web/staticfiles/ for static files in nginx
But in code it is located in /home/app/web/static folder

Answer (score 0):

rename the folder `static` to `static_volume`